# why there is a different types of output for different float comparisons

Tags: c

I have the following code
**Case 1**

```
float a=1.7;
    if(a==1.7)
    {
        printf("Equal\n");
    }
    else if(a<1.7)
    {
        printf("less\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Greater\n");
    }
```

**Output**

```
Greater
```

**Case 2**

```
float a=1.3;
if(a==1.3)
{
    printf("Equal\n");
}
else if(a<1.3)
{
    printf("less\n");
}
else{
    printf("Greater\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
Less
```

Why the outputs are not as expected?
Why the outputs are different in both cases?
Can anyone explain how the values are stored and compared here
Thanks in advance

Comment: `a` is a `float` and 1.7 is  `double`.  Due to assignment to the nearest FP value, 1.7 to  `float` and 1.7 to `double`, they differ.

Comment: When you are writing a=1.3, it's not exactly storing 1.3. It can be 1.3000000001 or also can be 1.29999999. It depends on compiler. So to check if two floating number is equal you have to use fabs(). You can write this,

if(fabs(a-1.3)<1e-6)
{
    printf("Equal\n");
}

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ which explains very well all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a combination of things -

- internally C uses double; float is a storage format.
- 1.3 is an infinitely repeating decimal when expressed in binary
- IEEE floating-point rounds the mantissa when storing it.  1.3 stored as a float gets
  rounded down, and 1.7 gets rounded up (by a tiny bit)
- the float a when read will be converted to a double by adding extra digits of
  least significant bits set to 0's.  Values that were rounded down are less than they
  were.  Values that were rounded up, even though they end in all zeros, are greater.
- and when comparing 1.xyzxyz000000 to 1.xyzxyzxyzxyz where not all of the xyz is 0,
  the one ending in zeros will be less.

Edit: missed the ieee rounding aspect earlier

For the curious, here is the actual value stored for 1.3 and 1.7 as 32-bit floats:
1.299999952316284179687500000000
1.700000047683715820312500000000

and as 64-bit floats:
1.30000000000000004440892098500626161694526672363281250000000000000000
1.69999999999999995559107901499373838305473327636718750000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a `float` a literal and then compare the result to the same literal, you should see that the values are equal. The trouble is, in your code you are not comparing a `float` to `float`: it is a `float` to `double` comparison.

Constants `1.7` and `1.3` are of type `double`. When you compare them to a `float`, the value of `float` gets expanded to `double` before the comparison. This is the stage at which the values become non-equal: unless the constant is represented exactly (neither `1.7` nor `1.3` can be represented exactly in a floating point number) there will be a conversion error.

You can address this by comparing to a `float` constant: if you cast your constants to `float` before comparison, the equality checks would succeed:

```
float a=1.7;
if(a==(float)1.7) {
    printf("Equal\n");
} else if(a<(float)1.7) {
    printf("less\n");
} else {
    printf("Greater\n");
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/w8M5Mn) (prints `Equals`).

Answer (score 1):

In checking case it will consider an integer. so it will roundup the floating value to 
  integer.

```
1.7  roundup as 2. 
1.3  roundup as 1.
```

so this is the reason for that answer.